# How to deploy NextJS with NGINX?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, next.js

So I know how to deploy a React app on a server.

- npm run build
- create a server block and point the root to my react app folder build (**root /var/www/xfolder/build;**)
- systemctl restart nginx
- run my node server (nohup node server &&) and its done.

I feel kind of dumb for not understanding this with NextJS. I run npm run build
[image]

I'm expecting something like a build folder. I've tried setting the server block root to
**/var/www/xfolder/.next** but the page still gives 403 forbidden. And do I need to run npm run start? I'm confuse on how to properly deploy the app. I'm using Ubuntu, NginX (1gb droplet) in DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 21):

Check this: https://gist.github.com/iam-hussain/2ecdb934a7362e979e3aa5a92b181153

Reference for HTTP/HTTPS: https://gist.github.com/iam-hussain/2ecdb934a7362e979e3aa5a92b181153

Start PM2 nextJS service on port 8080:

- `cd PROJECT_DIRECTORY`
- `pm2 start "npm run start -- -p 8080" --name contractverifier`

Configure Nginx:

Replace this file with the below code `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
    server {
        server_name www.DOMAINNAME.com DOMAINNAME.com;

        index index.html index.htm;
        root /home/ubuntu/PROJECT_FOLDER; #Make sure your using the full path

        # Serve any static assets with NGINX
        location /_next/static {
            alias /home/ubuntu/PROJECT_FOLDER/.next/static;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, immutable";
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html # only serve html files from this dir
            @public
            @nextjs;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600";
        }

        location @public {
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600";
        }

        location @nextjs {
            # reverse proxy for next server
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; #Don't forget to update your port number
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80;
}
```

Comment: There is no sense in the `@public` component of the `try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html @public @nextjs;` directive. Only the last parameter can be used to specify a fallback (using either a new URI or a named location name). This `@public` one will be treated as a plain filename relative to your webserver root; this check will never succeed, giving only an extra performance impact due to the extra and useless system `stat` call; the `location @public { ... }` will never be chosen to handle any request at all.

Answer (score 15):

I managed to make it work. The problem is on my Nginx server block. I just add this block

```
location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

then run

```
npm start
```

[image]

Comment: @Wilker on your serverblock nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/[name-of-config]

Comment: could you share how to deploy nextjs from your experience? i stuck still now... hope you can help. i have a server in digitalOcean. I changed it to Nginx from Apache. I realised Apache cannot to run nodeJs App. Could you share me the nginx conf setup for nextjs app, 1. do you have /etc/nginx/nginx.conf in your server? if yes, could you share me what inside is it. 2. /etc/nginx/sites-available server code. =)

Comment: you dont need to update your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, what you need to do is to properly set up your nginx virtual environment for a specific domain. Once set up (your domain is pointing on your DigitalOcean vps server), add the location directive above on your /etc/nginx/sites-available/[your-configuration]. Then do systemctl restart nginx.

Comment: Thank you for your time.. i'd try it.. thanks!

Comment: Julio, May i know where the root file you point in the /etc/nginx/sites-available. eg: root /var/www/projectName/html; index index.html index.htm index.ngin-dabian.html; i wanna ask is the html and index file.. where is should be correct in nextjs App

Comment: the root should point at /var/www/projectName after making change, run (systemctl restart nginx) and make sure you also run (npm run build) on /var/www/projectName

Comment: i tried it, it still cannot show the project =(. Do you have setting Reverse Proxy Server on nginx in /etc/nginx/sites-available/projectName?

Comment: ohh.. maybe need pm2. i take a look for this. hope it solve my issue!

Comment: Yes, I also use pm2. My process is usually like this, 1) git pull origin main  2) npm run build  3) pm2 restart [processname]

Comment: what custom server are you using? node?

Comment: yes, i guess it should be node, in nextjs app default server are expressJs. Great, i using pm2 now, but i facing 502 gateway error, do you face this issue before for SSL web in nodejs and running from pm2.

Comment: yes. Make sure go to your /var/www/website and run (npm run build) and (pm2 start [name-of-process])

Comment: the pm2 run the project should be 3000 port? i guess maybe the port dont match each other. so causing this error. you didn't face this before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225975/discussion-between-julio-de-leon-and-wilker).

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to `pm2` in order to start `nextJs` service and `Nginx` for publishing it

pm2 cmd:

```
pm2 start yarn --name nextjs --interpreter bash -- start
pm2 show nextjs
```

You can push that config into `/etc/nginx/conf.d/your-file.config`
`/etc/nginx/nginx.config`

```
server {
    listen 80; # you can use 443 and letsencrypt to get SSL for free
    server_name dicom-interactive.com; # domain name
    access_log /var/log/dicom-interactive/access.log; # mkdir dir first
    error_log /var/log/dicom-interactive/error.log error;

    # for public asset into _next directory
    location _next/ {
        alias /srv/udemii-fe/.next/;
        expires 30d;
        access_log on;
    }

    location / {
        # reverse proxy for next server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; # your nextJs service and port
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # we need to remove this 404 handling
        # because next's _next folder and own handling
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```