# React app and Next js under same Production fe url

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having two projects one is done in next js which is serving static pages and the other is in react which is serving logical and auth parts.
now I want to know is there any way to serve both the projects in the same URL
for example:

```
www.charan.com/blog //is coming from nextjs
www.charan.com //is coming from nextjs
www.charan.com/protected //is coming from react app
www.charan.com/login //is coming from react app
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! There are countless alternatives but I would accomplish this by setting up `nginx` as a reverse proxy. There is a question covering this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64386737/how-to-deploy-nextjs-with-nginx).

When `nginx` works with just nextjs, you can define another `location` (or multiple) in the config file and either forward it to another webserver which serves your `react` page on a local port or let `nginx` serve the `index.html` file directly:

```
location /protected {
        try_files $uri /react-app-folder/index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
    }
```

It will take some playing around since you need to make sure the JS and CSS files are served from the correct directory but this should give you enough information how this can be accomplished and some new Google keywords to look for.

Comment: thanks for the answer what if i dont use nginx how can i achieve this if i was using digital ocean or aws platforms